Ignore all wordpress folder except my specific plugin
I'm working on a wordpress plugin as part of a larger project. The wordpress install sits in a wordpress folder, I want to ignore all of the wordpress install except the specific plugin that I'm working on, so everything in the plugin folder, and all subfolders need to be included.
This is what I've got so far
wordpress/
!wordpress/

wordpress/*
!wordpress/wp-content/

wordpress/wp-content/*
!wordpress/wp-content/plugins/

wordpress/wp-content/plugins/*
!wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin

This works to ignore all the wordpress stuff except the my_plugin folder. Everything I've read suggests that the last line should be some form of !wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/* or !wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/** but not only does that not work, it makes the my_plugin folder disappear from the list of changed files entirely. !wordpress/wp-content/plugins/yourbookng_listing_plugin/ works the same as !wordpress/wp-content/plugins/yourbookng_listing_plugin, the folder appears but none of the files or subfolders
If its relevant, I'm using github desktop.

The .gitignore file is parsed from top to bottom, so you should rewrite it as follow:
!wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin
wordpress/



I tried that and the folder itself isn't listed in the changes anymore
